# Issue with "arithmetic operation resulted in overflow"

Tags: c#

I have this expression

```
 long balance = (long)answer.Find(DppGlobals.TAG_TI_BALANCE).Get_QWORD();
```

which raises exception that there was overflow. The value on the right hand side is of unsigned type and has value: 18446744073708240732.

How to avoid this exception, use `unchecked`?

PS equivalent C++ implementation returned balance = -1310984, I need same value here too.

Why is there such an exception?

---

By using unchecked indeed now also on C# side I get -1310984. Can someone advice, am I losing data somehow?

Comment: Well what does the stack trace look like? Is it definitely in the cast? What's the return type of `Get_QWord()`? (And is there any reason you're violating normal .NET naming conventions with both that and `TAG_TI_BALANCE`, as an aside?) Without knowing what the code is doing, it's very hard to give good advice.

Comment: @JonSkeet:  Yes I checked it is definitely in the cast. QWORD is ulong. I would appreciate your advice

Answer (score 2):

Using `uncheck` will also crop your value, but you will not have an **exception**,you will get **wrong** number.I think you will do something changing your code, not mask your exception.

```
long balance = (unchecked))(long)answer.Find(DppGlobals.TAG_TI_BALANCE).Get_QWORD());
```

**Why is there such an exception?**

It is a very good that you get an error.Because if you are working in the sphere where everything is numbers, you can have a mistake and don't understand this.So the RunTime will show you your eror

Comment: Yes using unchecked now I also get  -1310984 on C# side. What do you mean it is cropped are you sure?

Comment: if its range don't feet into the range of long it will crop your number.So if you have(example for int)a big number and your try to assign it into int variable it will crop the number to fit into the int.So you will get a wrong number

Comment: I see bit originally this value was sent as long. Then converted to ulong then again to long as in my question. Why overflow?

Comment: because the range of ulong is large than long

Comment: @user200312: Well if the value was originally -1310984 then you almost certainly shouldn't have converted it to a `ulong` to start with... maybe `Get_QWORD()` should return a `long` instead.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan: No it's not. They're both 64 bits. They just have different origins.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Dear John I understand but I can't avoid that my protocol is like that (it was error by previous programmer). What can I do? Fixing is not really option it is about serializing and all integer values are treated as unsigned by serializer. But like I said in the database that value was stored like int

Comment: @JonSkeet yes.I tried to say that unlong is all positive numbers which's max value is long.MaxValue * 2

Comment: @user200312: If this isn't actually the result of arithmetic, just conversion between `long` and `ulong`, you won't lose any data and it's fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yep but why was there exception? I mean on the database it is stored as long. Then the serializer stores it as unsigned. And in my code as you can see I cast to long again. Why overflow?

Comment: @user200312 but is the Database's long equal to .Net long?

Comment: @user200312: There was an exception because presumably you're using checked arithmetic. It's overflowing because the value is too large (when viewed as a `ulong`) to store as a `long`.

Comment: @JonSkeet  is the Database's long equal to .Net long?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan: I have no idea what database the OP is using.

Comment: @user200312: Maybe - we can't tell. I'm writing an answer to clarify.

Comment: @user200312 I think your database's long type range is different from the .Net long's range.Try to search it's range

Answer (score 2):

Given the comments, it sounds like you do just need to use unchecked arithmetic - but you should be concerned about the use of `ulong` in your API. If your aim is to just propagate 8 bytes of data, and interpret it as either an unsigned integer or a signed integer depending on context, then you're fine - so long as nothing performs arithmetic on it in the "wrong" form.

It's important to understand why this happens though, and it's much easier to explain that with small numbers. I'll use `byte` and `sbyte` as an example. The range of `byte` is 0 to 255 inclusive. The range of `sbyte` is -128 to 127 inclusive. Both can store 256 different values. No problem.

Now, using unchecked conversions, it's fine to say:

```
byte a = GetByteFromSomewhere();
sbyte b = (sbyte) a;
StoreSByteSomewhere(b);
...
sbyte b = GetSByteFromStorage();
byte a = (byte) b;
```

If that's *all* you're doing, that's fine. A `byte` value of -1 will become an `sbyte` value of 255 and vice versa - basically it's just interpreting the same bit pattern in different ways.

But if you're performing other operations on the value when it's being handled as the "wrong" type, then you could get unexpected answers. For example, consider "dividing by 3". If you divide -9 by 3, you get -3, right? Whereas if you have:

```
byte original = -9;
sbyte converted = (sbyte) original;
sbyte divided = converted / 3;
byte result = (byte) divided;
```

... then you end up with a result of -2 instead of -3, due to the way the arithmetic worked.

Now that's all for *unchecked* conversions. When you have a *checked* conversion, it doesn't just interpret the bits - it treats the value as a *number* instead. So for example:

```
// In a checked context...
byte a = 128;
sbyte b = (sbyte) a; // Bang! Exception
```

That's because 128 (as a number) is outside the range of `sbyte`. This is what's happening in your case - the number 18446744073708240732 is outside the range of `long`, so you're getting an exception. The checked conversion is treating it as a *number* which can be range-checked, rather than an unchecked conversion just reinterpreting the bits as a `long` (which leads to the negative number you want).

Comment: Dear Jon, it seems I am having hard time to follow your answer fully, can you break it down a bit more? for beginner style? Thank you.

Comment: Also, what if I directly have `byte a = (byte) GetSByteFromStorage();?`

Comment: @user200312: It's "hard to break it down" without knowing which bit you're confused by. And yes, casting the result of the method call is exactly equivalent to storing the result in a local variable and then casting that.

Comment: @user200312: I've just realized that I haven't included anything about the exception though. Will do that now.

Comment: are you sure this `byte result = (byte) original;` is correct? last line. I am confused when it can result in problem, where does the arithmetic have to occur for me to get wrong results?

Comment: @user200312: Sorry, that was a typo - fixed.